# SQL to get list of product name, sku and quantity sold in a year

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, magento-1.8

I want to get a full list of products sold in a year, grouped by Product Name or SKU.

I have tried using the *Admin Reports > Products > ProductsOrdered* and selected the Time Frame. However this gives wrong Data, maybe because we have Bundled products and we sell lots of Bundle products.

Any ideas on how this can be done by SQL?

Edit :

This is the current output, nothing wrong with the format but data given out is wrong.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Period | Product Name                                       | Quantity Ordered |
|-------|----------------------------------------------------|------------------|
|2015   | std charge charge (Per Sofa)                       | 96               |
|2015   | New Jersey 3 + 1 + 1 Seater Black Leather Sofa Set | 68               |
|2015   | New Jersey 3 + 1 + 1 Seater Black Leather Sofa Set | 60 [ Repeated?]  |
|2015   | Rex Black 3 + 2 GM200E                             | 52               |
..........
```

Comment: Check your locale selected may be it's wrong so your time generated was also wrong?

Comment: also, can you show us the current and expected output?

Comment: I would like to help you, but I don't know the exact db structure of magento. Could you show us the tables' structure?

Comment: @Takarii I have updated the  current output , nothing wrong with format . Just the Data given out is wrong .

Comment: @phaberest  This is where you can find Database diagram. Its too complex if you new to Magento https://blog.amasty.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/magento-database-diagram.pdf

Comment: It is not that complicated, but you'd have to do multiple joins. If I was you I'd tried to find the query to read the product/sales data as is, then you will be able to `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT()` what's needed. Not actually a 5 minutes task...

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from yourtable group by year,product_name;
```

or

```
select * from yourtable where date_column between 01-01-2016 and 31-12-2016 group by product_name
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT(product name) FROM(table name) WHERE (PERIOD=2015);
```